# Map 2 Array Attributes

Tags: javascript, arrays

I would like to return two attributes of an array

```
{
    label: 'Export',
    value: () => {

        let objects = [{category: 'Category 1', name: 'Test category 1'}, {category: 'Category 2', name: 'Test category 2'}];

        let object = objects
            .filter(object => !!object)
            .map(object => object.category)
            .join(', ');

        return cleanNewline(object);
    }
},
```

Right now, this code will return

> Category 1, Category 2

However, I also want to map the 'name' attribute so that the code will return

> Category 1 Test category 1, Category 2 Test category 2

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: @HereticMonkey wasn't relevant for the question, I removed it, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to map `name` as well.

```js
let objects = [{ category: 'Category 1', name: 'Test category 1' }, { category: 'Category 2', name: 'Test category 2' }],
    object = objects
        //.filter(object => !!object)
        .map(({ category, name }) => [category, name].join(' '))
        //.filter((value, key, array) => array.indexOf(value) === key)
        .join(', ');

console.log(object);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this would do:

```
function example() {
  let objects = [{category: 'Category 1', name: 'Test category 1'}, {category: 'Category 2', name: 'Test category 2'}]

  const result = objects.map(({category, name}) => `${category} ${name}`).join(', ')

  return result
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your goal simply doing this-

```js
let objects = [{category: 'Category 1', name: 'Test category 1'}, {category: 'Category 2', name: 'Test category 2'}];

objects = objects
  .filter(obj => !!obj)
  .map(obj => Object.values(obj).join(' '))
  .join(', ');
  
console.log(objects);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this code will however map all of the attributes, which is not the goal

Comment: Do you need just ```category``` and ```name```?

Comment: Yes exactly, so that I have those 2 specific fields returned

Comment: Then this is the correct answer I think - https://stackoverflow.com/a/60816788/4610740